# How do I write conditionals ifeq ($(filter-out tt_%,$(TARGET_PRODUCT)),) in android.bp

Tags: android, android-source

How do handle below code in Android.bp ? I need to enable conditional flag based on Target_product that is selected. I have shared my Android.mk , similar logic need to be handled in Android.bp.

In Android.mk I have below code

```
ifeq ($(filter-out ctt_%,$(TARGET_PRODUCT)),)

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DCTT_BUILD

else ifeq ($(filter-out ihu_%,$(TARGET_PRODUCT)),)

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DPHU_BUILD

LOCAL_SRC_FILES +=vendor_cmds.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += vendor_cmds.h
endif
```

Thanks in advance.

Your answers are really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is quite disappointing: you cannot write conditionals in Android.bp.

The long answer, which is also disappointing: you need a bootstrap_go_package, which can handle conditionals using a module written in go.
Refer to the answer to this question for a very simple example: [What is art.go? And why is it considered a way to write conditionals in bp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602427/what-is-art-go-and-why-is-it-considered-a-way-to-write-conditionals-in-bp-files)